# ng-bootstrap Alert disappears until full page refresh

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-library

I'm using ng-bootstrap and have added an Alert to a component.

```
<div *ngIf="!staticAlertClosed" (close)="staticAlertClosed = true" 
     style="width:100%;white-space:nowrap;float:left">
    <ngb-alert style="float: left" [dismissible]="false" [type]="type"> 
         {{message}} 
    </ngb-alert>
</div>
```

as you can see I've added the self closing timer

So after the Alert shows with an event then disappears(i've tried this with an event too) I have to do a full page refresh to have the Alert show again?

this doesn't seem useful since I might want to show an error alert and then a success alert when the user has corrected a problem.

Am I missing something? is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You might not be setting the `staticAlertClosed` to `true`. Make sure you are executing the statement whenever you want to show error / success message.

```
this.staticAlertClosed = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a configured behavior and expected. But there are too many unknowns here to tell exactly. First, you have the outer `*ngIf` set to `staticAlertClosed` - which on click you set to true. So it's going to remain closed "forever" - or until a page reload. If you want to show a new alert, you'd have to set it to false again.

Are you already doing this? If not, here's how it would look in an example component:

```
const DEFAULT_ALERT_TIMEOUT = 3000; // expire message after 3 seconds.
export class MyComponent implements NgOnInit {
    message: string;
    type: string;
    staticAlertClosed = true; // do not show by default
    constructor(private messages: MessagesService) {} // inject a service which provides fresh messages

    ngOnInit() {
        // subscribe to the new messages
        this.messages.alerts$.subscribe(alert => {
            // new message
            this.message = alert.message;
            this.type = alert.type;
            this.staticAlertClosed = false;
            // auto-close if not error
            if (alert.type !== 'error') {
                setTimeout(() => this.staticAlertClosed, DEFAULT_ALERT_TIMEOUT)
            }
        });
```

An alternative would be to track messages and show/hide each independantly. You can see examples of these on the [ng-bootstrap page](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/examples).